# How to make a program back to a certain line?

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

In this assignment I have to make a choose your own ending game using if statements, I want to make it so when the user inputs a certain choice it will go to the next statement, but the thing is the statement is behind the one I want to add is a few statements behind, here's what I have so far...

```
System.out.println("senario1"
                + "\n"
                + "\n1) choice1"
                + "\n2) choice2");
        int choice3 = key.nextInt();

if (choice3 == 1)
        {
System.out.println("senario2"
                + "\n"
                + "\n1) choice3"
                + "\n2) choice4"
                + "\n3) choice5");
        int choice4 = key.nextInt();
            if (choice4 == 3)
            {

            }
        }
        else if (choice3 == 2)  
        {
        System.out.println("senario3"
                + "\n"
                + "\n1) choice6."
                + "\n2) choice7."
                + "\n3) choice8."
                + "\n4) choice9.");
        }
```

I want to make it so that if the user chooses choice3 it will send them to senario3 instead of continuing forward. I tried to do a one of those while-continue ones but I couldn't figure it out and from reading up I don't think that's the right solution.

I'm using Java and my IDE is Eclipse.

Comment: The instructions will be executed one after the other. Going back from B to A means you want to repeat what’s between A and B. To repeat portions of code, use a while-statement: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop

Comment: In Java, your code is executed one line at a time and they move in order; there is no "simple" way to just go back to a previous line of code and that is definitely not proper Java to do so.

Has your class not discussed loops or methods yet? If not, you will need to structure your `if/then` statements in such a way that they lead where you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand what you want to do. But take a look at functions and while/for loops. You can "safe" certain lines (blocks) as a function and call it. You can call the function more than one time.

Example:

```
public void numOne()
{
    System.out.println("First function");
}

public void numTwo()
{
    System.out.println("Secondfunction");
}
```

And you call them:

```
numOne();
numTwo();
numOne();
```

I hope I helped you. If this doest help give me more context and try to explain you problem better.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, put your scenario choices in `methods` which works like functions. So that every time you want to call a specific scenario you can just refer to that function which holds the scenario you want.

```
//Define scanner outside method for all methods to access 
static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

//First method for the first choice scenario
public static void choice1(){
   System.out.println("senario2" + "\n" + "\n1) choice3" + "\n2) choice4" + "\n3) choice5");
   int choice4 = key.nextInt();
   if (choice4 == 3 ){
       choice2(); //Calls the second choice method which takes the program to the second choice
    }
}

//Second method for the second choice scenario
public static void choice2(){
   System.out.println("senario3" + "\n" + "\n1) choice6." + "\n2) choice7." + "\n3) choice8." + "\n4) choice9.");
}
```

Then in main method :

```
System.out.println("senario1" + "\n" + "\n1) choice1" + "\n2) choice2");
int choice3 = key.nextInt();

if (choice3 == 1) {
  choice1(); //Calls first method to go to
} else if (choice3 == 2) {
  choice2(); //Calls the second method to go to
}
```

Putting your scenario choices in methods will give you more control to refer to them as many times as you need whenever. In java you can't jump to any specific line so instead `methods` are used to access the block of code you need.

ALTOGETHER

```
static Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void choice1(){
   System.out.println("senario2" + "\n" + "\n1) choice3" + "\n2) choice4" + "\n3) choice5");
   int choice4 = key.nextInt();
   if (choice4 == 3 ){
     choice2();
   }
}

public static void choice2(){
   System.out.println("senario3" + "\n" + "\n1) choice6." + "\n2) choice7." + "\n3) choice8." + "\n4) choice9.");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("senario1" + "\n" + "\n1) choice1" + "\n2) choice2");
   int choice3 = key.nextInt();
   if (choice3 == 1) {
      choice1();
   } else if (choice3 == 2) {
      choice2();
   }

}
```

And then you can add more methods per scenario as needed

Comment: By the way if you're wondering, the reason `static` appears in front of the scanner is because methods with static attributes (such as the main method) can only reference other static attributes. That may be a bit ahead of what you are learning but overall to be able to reference blocks of code, the block of code needs to be put into a method so you can access it as often as you need to.